# copy contents of a section to another section, without disturbing section breaks?

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-2013

I have a source and a destination Word 2013 doc.  Each document has multiple section breaks with very particular footers in each of those sections which I cannot disturb.  I need to copy just the *contents* (without the section break) of a certain section from the source doc, and paste those contents to a certain section of the destination doc - e.g. copy the text of source section 3 to dest section 5.

The problem is that when I copy the source section, that copy command also includes the section break character from the source doc.  So when I paste it into the destination doc, it either blows away that dest section's break character (or adds a new section if that destination section was the last one in the document, and therefore did not have a section break character following it).

Is there a way in Word, with a VBA macro, to copy just the raw contents of a given section from the source document *without* copying that section's section break and paste them into a different doc **without blowing away that destination section's  section break**?

I have tried all sort of variations like this:

```
source.Sections(3).Range.Select
source.Sections(3).Range.Copy
dest.Sections(5).Range.Select
dest.Sections(5).Range.Paste
```

But the paste line disturbs the section breaks of the destination document.   I have also tried reducing the selection length from the source doc (before I copy it) by one character, hoping to exclude the section break:

```
source.Sections(3).Range.Select
source.ActiveWindow.Selection.MoveEnd Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:= -1  ' (I also tried -2, -3, etc)
source.Sections(3).Range.Copy
dest.Sections(5).Range.Select
dest.ActiveWindow.Selection.MoveEnd Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:= -1  ' (I also tried -2, -3, etc)
dest.Sections(5).Range.Paste
```

These reductions in the selection reduce the actual text of the section, but dont seem to exclude the section break, which I assume is in the selection range?

Comment: Deduplicator, if I searched for a long time on this site for this question and could not find it.   Do you mind telling me where this duplicate post is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks Cindy!   Your suggestion got me to where I needed to be.   Your code needed a little tweaking.  You dim'd rngSec as a Word.Section but it complains; I think you meant Word.Range, no?   And without doing a rng.select, the copy line complained that no text was selected.

Here is code to take the contents of the sections from one doc, and put them into reverse order in a different doc - without affecting any section breaks:

```
Option Explicit

Sub switch_sections()

Dim SourceDoc As Document, DestDoc As Document
Dim i As Integer
Dim has_section_break As Boolean

Set SourceDoc = Application.Documents("source.docx")
Set DestDoc = Application.Documents("destination.docx")

Dim SrcRng As Range    ' Word.Section
Dim DestRng As Range    ' Word.Section

For i = 1 To SourceDoc.Sections.Count
    With SourceDoc.Sections(i).Range.Find
        ' Check for a section break.  Put this find first, else it
        ' screws up the selection we will do below.
        .Text = "^b"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Format = False
        .Execute
        If .Found Then
            has_section_break = True
        End If
    End With

    Set SrcRng = SourceDoc.Sections(i).Range
    SrcRng.Select
    If has_section_break Then SrcRng.MoveEnd wdCharacter, -1
    SrcRng.Copy     ' Copy all but section break

    With DestDoc.Sections(DestDoc.Sections.Count - (i - 1)).Range.Find
        ' Check for a section break.  Put this find first, else it
        ' screws up the selection we will do below.
        .Text = "^b"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Format = False
        .Execute
        If .Found Then
           has_section_break = True
        End If
    End With
    Set DestRng = DestDoc.Sections(DestDoc.Sections.Count - (i - 1)).Range
    DestRng.Select
    If has_section_break Then DestRng.MoveEnd wdCharacter, -1

    DestRng.Paste   ' Replace all but the section break
   Next
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that you don't copy the thing where you move the end. Changing a Selection does not affect a Range.

Its's betterto work directly with the Range object than with Selection. The MoveEnd method ought to work with that. Try something like this

```
Dim rngSec as Word.Range
Set rngSec = source.Sections(3).Range
rngSec.MoveEnd wdCharacter, -1
rngSec.Copy
```

Comment: Thanks Cindy!   Your suggestion got me to where I needed to be!   Your code needed a little tweaking, but here is the final code to switch the contents of a section from one doc, into a different doc without affecting the section breaks:

Comment: Glad it helped:-) As I see you're new to Stack Overflow:It's customary to up-vote helpful comments and Answers and to mark an Answer as such by clicking the checkmark under the voting arrows.

Comment: When you have enough "rep" put the check mark under your answer - it's more complete. And, yes, that was a typo (which I'm fixing). I would have expected the Range to copy without selecting... Interesting that it wouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

I looked all over the Internet, and reworked the code so that it will work for what I need. This simply copies from one document to another and does not remove any of the existing headers and footers. You can past this into your existing code, or create a separate sub routine but you will have to perhaps pass some variables.

```
Dim oSec As Section
    Dim oHead As HeaderFooter
    Dim oFoot As HeaderFooter
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
    For Each oSec In ActiveDocument.Sections
        For Each oHead In oSec.Headers
            If oHead.Exists Then oHead.Range.Delete
        Next oHead
    For Each oFoot In oSec.Footers
        If oFoot.Exists Then oFoot.Range.Delete
    Next oFoot
Next oSec
' Now remove all section breaks - This is key
With Selection.Find
.Text = "^b"
.Replacement.Text = ""
.Forward = True
.Wrap = False
.Format = False
.MatchCase = False
.MatchWholeWord = False
.MatchKashida = False
.MatchDiacritics = False
.MatchAlefHamza = False
.MatchControl = False
.MatchWildcards = False
.MatchSoundsLike = False
.MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

Selection.WholeStory
Selection.Copy ' Copy the entire document
HoldingFileName.Activate
Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdStory
Selection.InsertBreak Type:=wdPageBreak
DoEvents
         
Selection.Paste
DoEvents
' Unselect from source
HoldingFileName.Activate
DoEvents
ActiveDocument.Range(0, 0).Select
ActiveDocument.Save
```